# Cannot Open Terminal After Recent System Upgrade

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I recently took all the system updates from the Ubuntu automatic updates.  This broke at least 2 things for me.  I was using xrcp to connect to the server but now it doesn't connect.  More importantly however, I cannot open the terminal application to debug.  Anything I do to open it doesn't work.

Things I've Verified

1. Language is set correctly (as mentioned in other threads)
2. I can open xterm
3. Python is still back at version 2.x so I'm thinking it is not the Python version (as mentioned in other threads)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you have synaptic you can re install what you need from there.

Comment: pls tell us what version of ubuntu you are using. perhaps also give us links to the "other threads". on the one side you write you can't open terminal, than you write you can open xterm, so i guess you have access to a terminal?